# How to filter pandas dataframe using lambda function with regular expression to extract date

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a pandas dataframe like below (with millions of rows) -

```
data = {'s3_path': ['s3://mybucket/date=2023-10-26/f1.txt', 's3://mybucket/date=2023-10-25/f2.txt', 's3://mybucket/date=2023-10-24/f3.txt', 's3://mybucket/date=2023-10-23/f4.txt']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to filter S3 paths that are before `2023-10-24`. What would be an efficient way to do that in pandas? Not knowing a lot about pandas, what I can think of is below, but it is not still complete:

```
date_cutoff_str = '2023-10-24'
date_cutoff_obj = datetime.strptime(date_cutoff_str, '%Y-%m-%d')

def is_before(cur_date, cutoff_date):
    if cur_date < cutoff_date:
        True
    return False

date_regex_pattern = r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}'
filtered_df = df.apply(is_before, cur_date=how_do_i_get_regex_value_here, cutoff_date=date_cutoff_obj)
```

Any suggestion/answer would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution, which uses regex to extract the dates as strings, and then converts them to `datetime` to compare with `2023-10-24`:

```
df.loc[
    pd.to_datetime(
        df['s3_path'].str.extract(r'date=(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})')[0])
    .lt('2023-10-24')]
```

Output:

```
                                s3_path
3  s3://mybucket/date=2023-10-23/f4.txt
```

Comment: I think that's exactly what I'm looking for. I learned something new today about pandas. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Here is another approach similar to Paul's answer, which uses the `to_datetime` function to convert the string date in your text to a datetime object and uses this datetime to filter your dataset.**

```
date_cutoff_obj = pd.to_datetime('2023-10-24', format='%Y-%m-%d')
    #here we extracting the data and create new data column
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['s3_path'].str.extract(r'(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})'), format='%Y-%m-%d') 

#now we can use the Date column as filter using pandas

filtered_df = df[df['date'] < date_cutoff_obj]
#now we can remove the date column if we no longer need it

filtered_df.drop(columns=['date'],inplace=True)

print(filtered_df)
```

Note: This code will work as long as the date is in the following format: "YYYY,MM, DD" as this is how the regular expression extracts the date.

Comment: Thank you, @Mohamed Fathallah. Happy to learn another way to do this (yours is more step-by-step, so it is definitely easier to follow for me as a beginner in pandas). :)

Comment: @user1330974 Happy to help ^^